# How to get a field from from last row of an change log table in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the follow example. When calling Order.next I would expect to return a single order in the with the status `NEW`. However I am getting Orders in other `OrderStatus`.

If it matters this is using SQLite backend.

```py
class OrderStatus(enum.Enum):
    NEW = 0
    MAKING = 1
    MADE = 2
    COLLECTED = 3


class Order(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    updates = relationship("OrderUpdate", order_by = "OrderUpdate.position", collection_class=ordering_list('position'))

    @hybrid_method
    def next(self):
        order = Order.query                              \
            .filter(Order.status in [OrderStatus.NEW])   \
            .order_by(Order.id)                          \
            .first()
        return order

    @hybrid_property
    def status(self):
        update = OrderUpdate                        \
            .query.filter_by(order_id = self.id)    \
            .order_by(OrderUpdate.id.desc())        \
            .first()
        if update is None:
            return None
        return update.status


class OrderUpdate(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'order_updates'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    position = Column(Integer)
    status = Column('status', Enum(OrderStatus))
    comment = Column(String)
    order_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("orders.id"))
    order = relationship("Order", back_populates="updates")
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check, but I think the problem with line:

`.filter(Order.status in [OrderStatus.NEW])`

If you need to use `in` condition you need to use [sqlalchemy in_()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.operators.ColumnOperators.in_). So in your case it should be like this: `Order.status.in_([1, 2])`. Also you can do it without `in_()`:

```
Order.query.filter_by(Order.status=0).order_by(Order.id).first()
```

> **Note!** About **Enum**. This is not about Flask or Flask-SqlAlchemy. Just for you information.

```
# Python 3.6.1

class OrderStatus(enum.Enum):
    NEW = 0

0 in [OrderStatus.NEW]  # False
0 in [OrderStatus.NEW.value]  # True

val = OrderStatus(0)
val in [OrderStatus.NEW]  # True
```

Hope this helps.